# Guardar muchos scripts en un solo archivo y

Tags: php, javascript, html

Necesito una ayuda la cual ya he intentado muchas cosas, menos con `JQuery`, me gustaría saber si hay una forma de poner muchos `scripts` en un solo archivo, así como el `@inlude` de `css`, y llamarlos con algo así en un `HTML`: `<?php include 'include/top_navbar.php'; ?>` esto pero con links de jscript.

Se los agradezco mucho.

Comment: puedes hacer un `<script src="TU/RUTA.js"></script>` y dentro de ese fichero añadir todos los scripts

Comment: Esa no me sirvió, gracias ya lo solucioné!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con **import** puedes importar muchos archivos js.

```js
import '/modules/my-module.js';
import '/modules/my-module2.js';
import '/modules/my-module3.js';
```

Referencia:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import

Comment: Muchas Gracias Bro, muy buena solucion!!